# Explanation of Corollary 2.15. Hungerford's Algebra book

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, free-modules

> Corollary 2.15. If $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional subspaces of a vector space over a division ring $D$, then $dim V + dim W = dim (V \cap W) + dim (V + W)$.
> Sketch of proof. Let $X$ be a basis of $V \cap W, Y$ a (finite) basis of $V$ that
> contains $X$, and $Z$ a (finite) basis of $W$ that contains X (Theorem 2.4). Show that $X \cup (Y - X) \cup (Y - X)$ is a basis of $V + W$, whence $dim (V + W) = |X| + |Y - X| + |Z - X| = dim V \cap W + (dim V - dim V \cap W) + (dim W - dim V \cap W)$.

I don't know how the set difference of two bases is a basis so makes two parts of the proof not understandable:

1- How $X \cup (Y - X) \cup (Y - X)$ is a basis of $V + W$?

2- How $|Y - X| = (dim V - dim V \cap W)$?

Proving the theorem has been posted on MSE but this question is **not** a duplicate of those since my question is about understanding **the** proof that has been given by the book.

Comment: Hello! Please format your question appropriately with $\LaTeX$. Best,

Comment: Good. Don't forget to use ```\dim``` to get $\dim V$ instead of $dim V$. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Corollary 2.15. If $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional subspaces of a vector space over a division ring $D$, then $\dim_D V + \dim_D W = \dim_D (V \cap W) + \dim_D (V + W)$.

Here are the details of the proof whose sketch is in Hungerford's book (page 187)

**Proof**: Let $X$ be a basis of $V \cap W$. Then $X \subset V$ and, since $X$ is linearly independent, by Theorem 2.4, there is  $Y$ a basis of $V$ that
contains $X$. Since $V$ is a finite dimensional space, we have that  $Y$ is finite (by Theorem 2.7). In a similar way there is $Z$ a finite basis of $W$ that contains $X$.

Let us list the elements of $X$, $Y - X$ and $Z-X$. So,
$ X =\{x_1, \dots x_r \} $,
$ Y - X = \{y_1, \dots y_s \} $ and
$ Z - X = \{z_1, \dots z_t \} $.
Note that the sets $X$, $Y - X$ and $Z-X$ are disjoint.

Now, let $B= X \cup (Y - X) \cup (Z - X)$.

Let us prove that $B$ is linearly independent. Suppose
$$ a_1 x_1 + \dots + a_r x_r+ b_1y_1 +\dots b_s y_s + c_1 z_1 + \dots c_t z_t =0 \tag{1}$$
Then
$$ -(c_1 z_1 + \dots c_t z_t) = a_1 x_1 + \dots + a_r x_r+ b_1y_1 +\dots b_s y_s  \tag{2}$$
Clearly, $-(c_1 z_1 + \dots c_t z_t) \in W$, as $Z$ is a basis of $W$. From the equality above, we also have that $-(c_1 z_1 + \dots c_t z_t) \in V$ (because $X \cup (Y-X)$ is $Y$, a basis of $V$). So, $-(c_1 z_1 + \dots c_t z_t) \in V\cap W$. So, $-(c_1 z_1 + \dots c_t z_t)$ can be written as a linear combination of elements in $X$:
$$  -(c_1 z_1 + \dots c_t z_t) = d_1 x_1 + \dots + d_r x_r  $$
that is
$$  -(c_1 z_1 + \dots c_t z_t) = d_1 x_1 + \dots + d_r x_r + 0y_1 +\dots 0 y_s \tag{3} $$
Since $X \cup (Y-X)$ is $Y$, a basis of $V$, $-(c_1 z_1 + \dots c_t z_t)$ can be written in a single way as a linear combination of elements in $X \cup (Y-X)$.
So, from $(2)$ and $(3)$, we have that $b_1=\cdots=b_s=0$. So, $(1)$ reduces to
$$ a_1 x_1 + \dots + a_r x_r+ c_1 z_1 + \dots c_t z_t =0 $$
But, $X \cup (Z-X)$ is $Z$, a basis of $W$ and so, linearly independent. So $a_1= \cdots = a_r= c_1 = \cdots = c_t=0$. So, $B$ is linearly independent.

Now, given any $v \in V$, $v$ can be written as a linear combination of elements in $X \cup (Y-X)$. Given any $w \in W$,   $w$ can be written as a linear combination of elements in $X \cup (Z-X)$. So $v+w$ can be written as a linear combination of elements in $X \cup (Y-X) \cup (Z-X) $. So, any element in $V+W$ can be written as a linear combination of elements in $B$. Since $B \subset V+W$, we have that $B$ is a basis of $V+W$.

Now, note that $\dim_D(V\cap W)  = r =|X|$, $\dim_DV = r+s= \dim_D(V\cap W) +|Y-X| $ and $\dim_DW = r+t= \dim_D(V\cap W) +|Z-X| $.
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\dim_D(& V+W)  = |B| = |X| + |Y - X| + |Z - X|  = \\
& = \dim_D(V\cap W) + (\dim_D V-\dim_D(V\cap W)) + (\dim_D W-\dim_D(V\cap W)) =\\
& = \dim_D V + \dim_D W - \dim_D (V\cap W)  
\end{align*}

So, we have:
$$ \dim_D V + \dim_D W = \dim_D (V \cap W) + \dim_D (V + W)$$